# Как правильно называются эти выражения?

Tags: словосочетание

Доброго всем здравия.
Я в гуманитарных науках не силён.
Поэтому и обращаюсь за помощью.
Хотел бы узнать, как называются словосочетания постоянно используемые в тексте.
Типа "периодические словосочетания", но не фразеологизмы же они. И как они правильнее называются?
И которые можно использовать в тексте своей работы, и они не будут считаться плагиатом.
Например это:

> *Федеральный закон "О внесении изменений в отдельные законодательные акты Российской Федерации в связи с совершенствованием принципов определения цен для целей налогообложения"*

Comment: Вспомнил!  
Регулярные выражения - они называются.

Comment: Гм... 
А кем именно они так называются?
В математике есть такой термин, но чтоб в лингвистике...

Comment: Устойчивые  словосочетания.

Comment: @behemothus Именно кем? Ну мной.. Я их так по незнанию назвал.
Почему и пошёл за советом к специалистам. Т.е. сюда.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Регулярные выражения - это в языке программирования,а в лингвистике это клише, в деловой речи юристов говорят "стандарт", где-то говорят "шаблон".

Comment: >Регулярные выражения - это в языке программирования  
  
В каком? Вообще-то это чистая математика...
А в языках программирования (вернее сказать даже сказать - их трансляторах/интерпретаторах) используется в несколько другом смысле. Причем - несколько разном в разном языках.

Comment: @Людмила
Т.е. Мне можно смело говорить, что в тех или иных работах, есть определённое количество (определённый процент) шаблонов, или клише, или стандартов?
Как правильнее в устной речи употребить, что там-то и там то, есть эти самые выражения?

Comment: Может быть, *устойчивые выражения*?

Comment: Могут  быть  и  устойчивые  выражения,  и  устойчивые  словосочетания.

Comment: В тех или иных работах есть определённое количество (определённый процент)  стандартных выражений. Мы говорим:"В канцелярско-деловой речи используются речевые штампы(клише)",или:"в юриспруденции и делопроизводстве существует   официальный стандарт речи". Т.е. отдельные выражения типа"Справка дана в том..."-клише,штамп, "заявление кому кого" - общий стандарт , т.е. приём оформления.

Comment: Допустим:
**Проведя анализ действия статьи УК РФ 158, на практике, которая гласит:
> 1. Мошенничество, то есть хищение...
** Мною было выяснены следующие слабые стороны...
---
Вот приведение текста, т.е. цитата стати - это что?
Так и говорить: цитаты не входят в процент неуникальности документа при его аналитике на предмет авторства.

Comment: Я не очень поняла, о чём речь. Сама фраза построена грамматически некорректно. 1.Это практика гласит или статья УК? Придаточное предложение должно стоять сразу за тем, к которому относится.2."Проведя анализ, мною выяснены"-деепричастие относится к действию субъекта, а субъектом(подлежащим) оказывается слово "стороны". Это стороны проводили анализ? Возможна фраза:"Анализируя статью на предмет авторства,можно отметить следующие обстоятельства:1),2),..." А это действительно только цитата. Можно сказать:применение цитирования статьи 158 УК РФ, которая гласит:"Мошенничество, то есть хищение..."

Comment: Вроде понял.  
Допустим: *В статье автора использованы - 35% оригинального, авторского текста, 15% цитат, стандартных выражений и 50% заимствованного текста из других источников.*  
Вот это корректно звучит?

Comment: Вполне. Точнее будет так:Статья является оригинальным текстом лишь на 
35 %,15% текста состоит из цитат и шаблонных выражений,50% - компиляция "пиратских"заимствований из чужих работ(если сгладить - из других источников).

Answer (score 1):

Вы, вероятно, имеете ввиду речевые штампы:
"... **«речевой штамп»** так называют стереотипные выражения, имеющие канцелярскую окраску.
Среди речевых штампов,..., можно выделить прежде всего **шаблонные обороты** речи: на данном этапе, в данный отрезок времени, на сегодняшний день, подчеркнул со всей остротой и т.п.  К речевым штампам относят также **универсальные** слова, которые используются в самых различных, часто слишком широких, неопределенных значениях (вопрос, мероприятие, ряд, проводить, разворачивать, являться, отдельный, определенный и т.п.). Например, существительное **вопрос**, выступая как универсальное слово, никогда не указывает на то, о чем спрашивают (Особо важное значение имеют вопросы питания в первые 10-12 дней; Большого внимания заслуживают вопросы своевременного сбора налога с предприятий и коммерческих структур)". (Голуб И.Б. Стилистика русского языка. М., 1999.)
Либо, возможно, фразеологизмы:
Разговорные (без году неделя, во всю ивановскую, водой не разольешь); научные (центр тяжести, щитовидная железа, периодическая система); публицистические (шоковая терапия, прямой эфир, черный вторник, закон джунглей); официально-деловые (минимальная зарплата, потребительская корзина, давать показания, конфискация имущества).(Классификация - тот же источник) 
Использование фразеологизмов вряд ли можно считать плагиатом)))

Comment: Прввильно.  Речевые  штампы  это  тоже  устойчивые  словосочетания.